# Laravel 5.3 select pluck method

Tags: php, laravel, pluck

Controller method:

```
public function edit($id){

    $match2 = Match::pluck('team_a_id', 'id');
    return view('admin.accept.edit', compact('match2'));

}
```

And view file:

```
{{ Form::select('matches_id', $match2, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

And my table:

Table from model `Match` (table name: matches):

[image]

Table from model `Team` (table name: teams):

[image]

Table `teams` is connected (references) with table `matches`( `team_a_id` and `team_b_id` is connected with table `teams`). The `select` method with `view` returned me only `ID` with tables:

[image]

I need have `team_name` with table `teams` not `id`.
When I change method pluck:

```
$match2 = Match::pluck('id', 'id');
```

And view:

```
 {{ Form::select('matches_id', Team::find($match2)->team_a_id." vs. ".Team::find($match2)->team_b_id, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Laravel returned error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\football\football\resources\views\admin\accept\edit.blade.php)

**This is metohd edit so I must have highlighted record that was previously selected.**

Comment: Try outputting the contents of `$match2` to see what exactly you get. using `dd($match2);`.

Comment: @Jerodev This returned `dd()` https://images81.fotosik.pl/317/0dbc76714c0d776fgen.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I repair this. I write method:

```
public function edit($id){

    $match = Match::select()->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get();
    $selectedMatch = DB::table('usermatches')->find($id)->matches_id;

    return view('admin.accept.edit', compact('match', 'selectedMatch'));

}
```

And view:

```
  <select name="matches_id" id="matches_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="5">
    <option value=0>Wybierz wydarzenie</option>
      @foreach($match as $role)
          <option value="{{ $role->id }}" {{ $selectedMatch == $role->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
            {{ Team::find($role->team_a_id)->team_name }} vs. {{ Team::find($role->team_b_id)->team_name }} ({{$role->date}}; <?php echo date('G:i',strtotime($role->time)); ?> | Liga {{ League::find($role->league_id)->name }} | {{ Sport::find($role->sport_id)->name }}) 
          </option>  
      @endforeach
  </select>
```

In model view I compare `id` with two tables and it working ;)

```
{{ $selectedMatch == $role->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}
```